# Creating an Akka actor system on an Android

Tags: java, android, akka, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm trying to create an Akka actor system on an Android (Kitkat) device (with IntelliJ + gradle) using Java. First, I had to add the `multiDexEnabled` flag (and the multidex support android library) so that I could include the `com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.10:2.3.9` library (otherwise, I'd hit the 65535 dex function limit). Then, I started getting the following `lint` warning:

> message="Invalid package reference in library; not included in
>   Android: `java.lang.management`. Referenced from
>   `scala.sys.process.package.`." category="Correctness" priority="6"
>   summary="Package not included in Android" explanation="This check
>   scans through libraries looking for calls to APIs that are not
>   included in Android.

I suppressed this warning, was then able to build and started debugging the code. However, soon enough I encountered a `java.lang.VerifyError: scala/None$` exception during the creation of an ActorSystem.

What am I doing wrong? Should I be using an older Akka version (I also tried Akka version 2.1.0)? The code works when I switch to Lollipop, but I need it to work on Kitkat also, if possible. Thanks.

Comment: My (very) wild guess it that you'll need to manually add that package's jar to the classpath before building?